# Accessing the samba shared files from the raspi

Tags: samba, file-sharing, file-server

I've connected an external hdd and set up a samba server. It's working fine on windows, but I have trouble to access the files I copied on the raspi. The hdd doesn't show up as before the samba setup an in the shared folder, so I can't access it throug the /media folder.

I shared e folder at /share/multimedia which contains several subfolders (pictures etc.). In Windows I copied a file to multimedia/pictures. On the raspi there are no folders in multimedia, only "files". The status bar in the files says "pictures" inode/x-corrpted-Typ.

**update:**

```
Dateisystem     1K-Blöcke Benutzt  Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/root        13671000 4186428    8767084   33% /
devtmpfs           470180       0     470180    0% /dev
tmpfs              474788       0     474788    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs              474788   30496     444292    7% /run
tmpfs                5120       4       5116    1% /run/lock
tmpfs              474788       0     474788    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p6      69553   21471      48083   31% /boot
/dev/sda1      1921802520   78140 1824032320    1% /share
tmpfs               94956       0      94956    0% /run/user/999
tmpfs               94956       0      94956    0% /run/user/1001
```

**update 2:**

I'm guessing it's not a wrong setup but maybe something on the vlc server. If I SSH into the Pi the terminal shows this:

*accessing the Pi's terminal via SSH:*

```
seb@raspi:~ $ ls /share/Multimedia/Pictures/
filesystem_wallpaper.png
seb@raspi:~ $ ls /share/ -l
insgesamt 24
drwx------  2 root root  16384 Mai 11 13:10 lost+found
drwxrwsr--+ 5 root users  4096 Mai 12 09:11 Multimedia
drwxrwsrw-+ 2 root users  4096 Mai 11 19:09 Public
seb@raspi:~ $ ls /share/Multimedia/ -l
insgesamt 12
drwxrwxr-- 2 root users 4096 Mai 11 19:12 Music
drwxrwxr-- 2 root users 4096 Mai 12 09:15 Pictures
drwxrwxr-- 2 root users 4096 Mai 11 19:12 Videos
seb@raspi:~ $
```

Everything is fine.

The problem I had is still there. But it is only if I connect through the VNC client. Then the terminal (on the GUI) shows a different result:

*accessing the Pi's terminal via VNC Viever and a virtual desktop:*

```
seb@raspi:~ $ ls /share/Multimedia/Pictures
ls: Zugriff auf '/share/Multimedia/Pictures' nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung
seb@raspi:~ $ ls /share/ -l
insgesamt 24
drwx------  2 root root  16384 Mai 11 13:10 lost+found
drwxrwsr--+ 5 root users  4096 Mai 12 09:11 Multimedia
drwxrwsrw-+ 2 root users  4096 Mai 11 19:09 Public
seb@raspi:~ $ ls /share/Multimedia/ -
ls: Zugriff auf '-' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/share/Multimedia/:
ls: Zugriff auf '/share/Multimedia/Pictures' nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung
ls: Zugriff auf '/share/Multimedia/Music' nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung
ls: Zugriff auf '/share/Multimedia/Videos' nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung
Music  Pictures  Videos
seb@raspi:~ $
```

So I guess it is not a problem with how I set everything up but a problem on how the VNC server connetcts? It's the same user after all. But on the 2nd example it is telling me I don't have the rights to access it.

Comment: It’s ok. I’m only on mobile right now. I just discovered that in my ssh terminal everything is fine. Just on my virtual desktop where I wanted to have the picture it still does not work. So I guess everything is set up ok just however not accessible through the desktop even if it is the same user.

Comment: No problem. It seems you're making forward progress, and I think you are on the right track looking at the VNC connection. I've revised my "Answer", ha ha I should say "non-Answer" with a few thoughts on where to go from here. I'm confident you'll resolve this, and I hope you follow up here with an answer to your own question! The information will help others who have fallen into the same hole :)

Comment: Another update (I guess I'm "hooked" now :) - you're username is `seb`; the RPi's VNC server may have an affinity for the username `pi`. Look at that...

Answer (score 2):

[EDITED RESPONSE II]

I will guess that the `inode/x-corrpted` message may be due to some **permissions** issues between your RPi and your Windoze machine. If that's the case, your files are not actually corrupted. Your most recent update would seem to support this. I'm not familiar at all with VNC, but I've read this statement: `... you need to add the new users you created to VNC as it only has the pi user set-up as default.` Have you added your username & pwd to the VNC configuration?

From the looks of it (your latest revised post), things with RPi itself are "as they should be". That is to say, you do have a mount point, and from the terminal at least, you can read and write to the shared drive. If that's not the case, please clarify.

I do wonder if you can write to the `Public` folder through VNC? The permissions suggest you can:

```
drwxrwsrw-+ 2 root users  4096 Mai 11 19:09 Public
```

In any event, the fact that you can't read the contents of your Multimedia folder from VNC tells me that the issue is in the VNC layer. You seem conversant in the basics of all this stuff, so I'd recommend you look into VNC a bit more closely. If you don't make any headway, perhaps re-post your question with the term **VNC** in the subject line. I'd be useless helping with a VNC issue I'm afraid as I've never used it (well, hardly ever :)

Comment: Sorry but I wasn't home and the above answer was through mobile. I made a big update on the first post.